# Any alternative to nested if conditions in the below code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, nested-if

```
if(section1()){
  if(section2()){
    if(section3()){
     .
     .
     .
     // Upto 10 methods
       if(section10(){
         return true;
       }

    }
  }
}
```

I am writing validations for 170+ controls, divided into 10 sections. As per business logic, if first section method returns true, then execute second method, else return false and show message like for ex. "Title is missing". If second method is true then execute third method and so on..

Is there an alternative to the above code? I need alternative for nested if conditions.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: In F# there's something called Railway Oriented Programming that can help with that sort of thing and much more, and just the other day I stumbled upon [this attempt to do it in C#](https://davidelettieri.it/rop/'tagged/union'/'railway/oriented/programming'/c%23/2020/04/04/railway-oriented-programming-with-c.html).

Comment: You might want a loop. But you can just `return section1() && section2() ...;`

Comment: I like the name `Railway Oriented Programming`!

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I was typing that :D. Yes, it seems simple and chain. If you are only calling the next one in the line then why put in all the `If`s.

Comment: I think maybe using ROP would be shooting sparrows with cannons for this case, and it would take more work to adapt the technique better to C#. But it's a great idea to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want to do is loop through and invoke these methods and for each iteration, do something with the result and decide whether or not to move on to the next step.

It's hard to give specifics here because we don't know what these functions do, but we know they all return a boolean value. So if any of them returns false, you probably want to break the loop and return early.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples/gists of C# classes you can use to implement that.
Try to nest the `ValidationSummary` and `Validator` instances to simulate the nested `if()`s you had.
In each validator instance, you have to set the dynamic function (stored here in `Process`) to invoke during the validation for each section.
It's a more flexible and scalable solution I think.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ValidationSummary valSum = new ValidationSummary();

        Validator val1 = new Validator("section 1");
        val1.Process = () => { return true; };
        valSum.Validators.Add(val1);

        Validator val2 = new Validator("section 2");
        val2.Process = () => { return false; };
        valSum.Validators.Add(val2);

        valSum.Validate();

        Console.WriteLine("Result = " + (valSum.IsValid ? "YES" : "NO"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class ValidationSummary
{
    private bool m_valid = false;

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_valid;
        }
    }

    public List<Validator> Validators
    {
        get;
    }

    public ValidationSummary()
    {
        this.m_valid = false;
        this.Validators = new List<Validator>();
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        // Trigger all validators.
        foreach (Validator v in this.Validators)
        {
            if (v.IsValid == false)
            {
                // sudden death, so stop all validations.
                this.m_valid = false;
                return;
            }
        }

        this.m_valid = true;
    }
}

class Validator
{

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Use this property to encapsulate all validation rules and processes.
    public Func<bool> Process
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Execute();
        }
    }

    public Validator(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Process = null;
    }

    private bool Execute()
    {
        return (bool)this.Process.DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```